# backfilling data from one column into another

Tags: python, pandas

This is how my data looks like:

```
colA  colB
 a      1
 a      1
 c      2
 c      2
Nan     1 
 c      1
 a      2
Nan     2
```

I want to fill the Nans in colA. The result should look like the following:

```
colA  colB
 a      1
 a      1
 c      2
 c      2
 a      1 
 c      1
 a      2
 c      2
```

Row 5 gets filled with 'a' because colB = 1 and overall 1 in colB has been mapped to more a's than c's in colA

Row 8 gets filled with 'c' because colB = 2 and overall 2 in colB has been mapped to more c's than a's in colA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [mode](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mode.html) (ignoring draws) on the groups:

```
In [11]: df
Out[11]:
  colA  colB
0    a     1
1    a     1
2    c     2
3    c     2
4  NaN     1
5    c     1
6    a     2
7  NaN     2

In [12]: modes = df.groupby('colB')['colA'].transform(lambda x: x.mode().iloc[0])

In [13]: modes
Out[13]:
0    a
1    a
2    c
3    c
4    a
5    a
6    c
7    c
Name: colA, dtype: object
```

Use fillna to replace the mode only for the NaNs:

```
In [14]: df['colA'].fillna(modes)
Out[14]:
0    a
1    a
2    c
3    c
4    a
5    c
6    a
7    c
Name: colA, dtype: object

In [15]: df['colA'] = df['colA'].fillna(modes)
```

---

Note: reading the docs, this will raise if no item occurs at least once, so you may wish to use a more robust function in the transform:

```
def mymode(s):
    try:
        return s.mode().iloc[0]
    except IndexError:
        # just pick the first element, even though it occurs only once, even if it's NaN
        return s.iloc[0] if len(s) >= 1 else np.nan
```